# What exactly "subset" is in "tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory"?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, preprocessing

so I'm following the official keras tutorial [here](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_from_scratch/). However I couldn't really understand the `subset` and `validation_split` arguments of `tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory`.

How I use them is:

```
raw_train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    "aclImdb/train",
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=1337
)

raw_val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    "aclImdb/train",
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=1337
)
```

As I understand we're trying to split train data into validation of its 0.2. However we do the same for both "training" and "validation" subsets on same dataset with the same `validation_split` value which is 0.2. So isn't it supposed to take 0.2 of training data to `raw_train_ds` and 0.2 to `raw_val_ds` instead of 0.8, 0.2?

I checked the documentation from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/text_dataset_from_directory) which was not really useful. I also couldn't find any related questions. How does this work exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still relevant.

As stated in the documentation, '`subset`' must be '`training`' or '`validation`' but is only used if '`validation_split`' is used. But the documentation does not mention what the link between the value in '`validation_split`' and '`subset`' is.

If the `subset` is '`validation`' then the value in '`validation_split`' is used directly to split the dataset.
Ex:
If the dataset is 100 and the split is 0.2 and `subset` is `validation` then the size of the validation set will be 20 *(0.2 x 100)*.

On the other hand, if the `subset` is '`training`' then the size of the training data set will be *(1-`validation_split`) x data set*.
Ex:
If the dataset is 100 and the split is 0.2 and `subset` is `training` then the size of the training set will be 80 *((1-0.2) x 100)*.

This is really a bad design :-)